# Seaborn is jumbling x-axis tick labels, no longer referring to bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to write a little suite of regular seaborn plots, along with styling, to allow for regular production of similarly styled plots. I'm working on bar plots. Mostly this works fine, but if I have too many values on the x axis, and specifically, if the names are too long and plentiful, the axis tick labels get completely jumbled, meaning that the plot becomes useless.

I'd really appreciate any advice that could help me with making the ticks on the x axis always informative when I have a scenario where I have many value labels for the data I'm trying to visualise. I realise that I could stick the labels within the bars, but I'd like to keep this as x axis ticks.

See here for an example of the x axis becoming uninformative. The data I used is taken from here https://footystats.org/england/premier-league/xg:

[image]

Here's my example code:

```
def bar_plot(self,
            df: pd.DataFrame,
            x_var: str,
            y_var: str,
            x_label: str,
            y_label: str,
            y_line: float,
            rotate_x_labels: bool = False,
            export: bool = False,
            filepath: str = None):
    '''
    produces a bar plot. 
    '''
    plt.figure(figsize=self.figsize)

    ax = sns.barplot(data=df,
                    x=x_var,
                    y=y_var,
                    palette=self.plot_elems_palette)
    
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(0.75)
    ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(0.75)

    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', width=0.5)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', width=0.5)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', width=0.5)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', width=0.5)

    if x_label:
        ax.set_xlabel(x_label, fontweight='bold')

    if y_label:
        ax.set_ylabel(y_label, fontweight='bold')

    if y_line is not None:
        ax.axhline(y_line, 
                    color=self.plot_elems_colour, 
                    linestyle='--',
                    linewidth=0.5)

    if rotate_x_labels:
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

    ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=(self.font_size*0.5), rotation=45)

    if export:
        if filepath:
            plt.savefig(filepath, 
                        dpi=DPI, 
                        bbox_inches=BBOX)
        else:
            raise ValueError('filepath must be specified if export is True')

    plt.show()
```

this all exists within a class that initialises defaults for all my plotting methods, that looks like this:

```
class PlotBuilder:
    def __init__(self, 
                 figsize: tuple = FIGSIZE,
                 background: str = BACKGROUND,
                 body_colour: str = BODY_COLOUR,
                 plot_elems_colour: str = PLOT_ELEMS_COLOUR,
                 plot_elems_palette: list = generate_colour_palette(BODY_COLOUR),
                 grid_colour: str = GRID_COLOUR,
                 font: str = FONT,
                 font_size: int = FONT_SIZE):
        self.figsize = figsize
        self.background = background
        self.body_colour = body_colour
        self.plot_elems_colour = plot_elems_colour
        self.plot_elems_palette = plot_elems_palette
        self.grid_colour = grid_colour
        self.font = font
        self.font_size = font_size
```

Comment: **if the names are too long and plentiful, the axis tick labels get completely jumbled**, then make horizontal bars instead. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfGg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The labels appear jumbled because their *centers* are aligned below the ticks. It's visually more pleasing if you align the right ends of the labels below the ticks:

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.barplot(x=[f'very long label for bar #{i}' for i in range(10)], y=range(10))
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
```

[image]